# Error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" when instantiating object

Tags: java

I get the error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" when trying to instantiate an object from the 'Boat' class.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
package simpleboatapp;

/**
 *
 * @author ragarwala
 */
public class SimpleBoatApp {

    public class Boat {

        private float speed;
        final private float topSpeed = 90;
        private boolean sailPosition;

        public Boat()
        {
            speed = 0;
            sailPosition = false;
        }
        public void goFast (String boatName)
        {

            if (speed < topSpeed)
            {
                speed = speed + 10;
                sailPosition = true;
                System.out.println (boatName + "is raising the sail at speed of" + speed + "mph");
            }
            else
            {
                sailPosition = true; 
                System.out.println (boatName + "is raising the sail at maximum speed of" + speed + "mph");
            }
        }

    }

  /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boat simpleboat = new Boat(); <--- Error occurs for this line
        simpleboat.goFast("Destiny"); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions:

- **Put the `Boat` class into a different class file.**  If `Boat` is going to be a non-static class and you want to instantiate it inside a static class, it should be in its own file.
- **Make the `Boat` class static.**  If you make the `Boat` class static you'll be able to instantiate it inside of the `Main` function and the program will run.
- **Change how you instantiate the`Boat` class.**  You can instantiate it as follows:

  `Boat simpleboat = new Main().new Boat();`

  This will resolve the static/non-static conflict.

Comment: He doesn't. See the other answers,

Comment: 'Inside a static class' is not the issue either. See the other answers. Do.

Comment: @EJP I'm still learning Java so figuring this out will help me just as much as the OP.  Am I on the right track?  None of the other answers are upvoted so I don't know how good they are.

Comment: This is now better, but if you're still learning you should be asking questions, not answering them.

Comment: @EJP I figured I knew enough to answer this question...my original suggestion would have worked, right?  I just didn't know why.  As for asking, I can't for the life of me ask questions that get positive scores no matter how hard I try so I just ask people in real life for help if I need it.

Answer (score 1):

You `Boat` class does not need anything from the containing class `BoatApp`.

In that case you can declare it is a `static` member class using the `static` keyword and you'll be able to instantiate it from a static context.

```
public static class Boat {
```

When you declare a class inside another class, the default assumption is that the class inside may access the data in the outer class. Which means that it always need to have an instance of the outer class in scope.

You can search for "inner class" if you want to know more about that.

But in this case, your `BoatApp` is clearly not something that you want to access from within your member class `Boat` (it's just a holder for a `main` method) so you just need to declare `Boat` as `static`, or you move it to its own file.

Comment: Erwin ... thanks for the explanation.  That made sense.  Using the 'static' keyword also got my code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the `Boat` class enclosed within another class, `SimpleBoatApp`, while trying to statically instantiate a new `Boat` without the class that encloses it.

Instead, consider moving the `Boat` class outside the `SimpleBoatApp` class while leaving your `main` method inside your `SimpleBoatApp`:

```
public class SimpleBoatApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boat simpleboat = new Boat();
        simpleboat.goFast("Destiny"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the non static (inner) class which you can initiate like below

```
   Boat simpleboat = new SimpleBoatApp().new Boat();
```

If it would have static class, you could initiate like below

```
   Boat simpleboat = new SimpleBoatApp().Boat();
```